# JQuery Resize - Bring to Front

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, resizable

I've made several overlapping objects draggable and resizable via the JQuery [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/) plugins. When dragging an object, it's instantly brought up to the frontmost position thanks to the [stack](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-stack) option. The Resizable plugin doesn't have this option so when an element in the background is being resized but not dragged, it stays in the back.

How do I make an object being **resized** jump to the front just like it happens when it's being dragged?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this yourself by using the `start` event of the `resizable` widget.

In that event you just loop through your draggable/resizable elements to find the highest `zIndex`, then set your currently resizing element higher in the stack.

For example (heavily commented for clarity).

```js
// Common class of our draggable/resizable elements
const targetClass = ".foo";

$(targetClass)
  .resizable({
    start: (event, ui) => {
      // current resizing element
      const element = $(ui.element[0]);
      let topZIndex = 0;
      // loop over all our elements 
      $(targetClass).each((i, obj) => {
        // get the current zIndex as an int, using the unary operator
        // and accounting for NaN values like 'auto'
        const currentZIndex = +$(obj).css("zIndex") || 0;
        // if current zIndex is higher, update the topZIndex 
        currentZIndex > topZIndex && (topZIndex = currentZIndex);
      });
      // set the resizing elements zIndex above the highest
      element.css("zIndex", topZIndex + 1);
    }
  })
  .draggable({
    stack: targetClass
  });
```

```css
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  position: absolute !important;
}

.foo h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="container">
  <div class="foo ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">test 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="foo ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">test 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="foo ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">test 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Fraser for your quick reply - I didn't have time to implement this on my project yet, but I checked the snippet and it works perfect. I'll post an update as soon as I get it working. Cheers!

Comment: Confirming that this solution worked for me. Thanks again.